# Regular Expression xml java

Tags: java, xml, colors, expression

I have a xml tag with an attribute and a value of attribute:

How do I write regular expression to put:

```
<tag> - blue color
attribute - red color
= - black color
"value"  - violet color
```

For now I have

```
Pattern tagsPattern = Pattern.compile("<[^<>]*?>");
```

which works well and find everything between < and >. I don't know how to do the rest...

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. I could answer: _Print it and use color highlighters._ How do you want to display your xml in color? In a browser? console? text editor?

Comment: I made it: Pattern tagsPattern=Pattern.compile("<[^<>]*?>");
    Pattern atVPattern = Pattern.compile("\"[^=]*?\"");
    Pattern atPattern = Pattern.compile("\\s[a-zA-Z]*");